# Changing the web.config file programmatically using WebService.ApplyWebConfigModifications() method is giving Error

Tags: sharepoint-2010, web-config, fba

I have created the FBA site in SharePoint 2010 Farm. The site is allowing both the windows and FBA authentication. I have set the Server administrator (Member of Built in Administrator) as Application pool identity. The same account has sufficient permission in Sql server database for the site.

I have implemented one feature. The feature in turn is modifying the web.Config for the sites in farm. I have placed the code inside the SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges block.

```
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
    {
            Guid siteGuid = ((SPWeb)properties.Feature.Parent).Site.ID;

            Guid webGuid = ((SPWeb)properties.Feature.Parent).ID;

            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {

                using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteGuid))
                {
                    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb(webGuid))
                    {
                        SPWebApplication webApp = web.Site.WebApplication;  
                        SPWebConfigModification myModification = new SPWebConfigModification("add[@name=\"assembly\"]", "/configuration/system.web/compilation/assemblies");
                        myModification.Value = "<add assembly=\"MyAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9e00227b2bfdcg7e\"/>";
                        myModification.Sequence = 0;
                        myModification.Type = SPWebConfigModification.SPWebConfigModificationType.EnsureChildNode;
                        myModification.Owner = typeof(<MyWebpartNameGoesHere>).FullName;
                        webApp.WebConfigModifications.Add(myModification);
                        webApp.WebService.ApplyWebConfigModifications();
                        webApp.Update();

                                                        }
                                               }
                                     });
```

}

The Code is running perfectly fine for any windows user. But when I enter the site as FBA user and try to activate the feature, I start getting the “Access denied.” error.

Error:
System.Security.SecurityException: Access denied.
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPersistedObject.BaseUpdate()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebApplication.ApplyWebConfigModifications()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService.ApplyWebConfigModifications()

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You seriously have to consider if you want users to activate this code. 
Making web.config modifications is an administrators thing and not a users' thing.

Please read this: http://www.itidea.nl/index.php/access-denied-when-activating-a-feature/

Regards, Anita

Comment: +1 From the code you've shown, this feature should only be activated once. It should be hidden, scoped at the Web Application level, and activated on the server using PowerShell or STSADM.